# Including the same header file in two different classes

Tags: c++, directx

So I have class A, B, and C. Class A is the parent or base class and B and C inherit from it. I get errors saying "base class undefined" I believe it's because class A is included in both header files of B and C? This is in my main code.

```
#include "BoundingSphere.h"
#include "OrientedBoundingBox.h"
```

And this is the shortened version of BoundingSphere.h

```
#include "Model.h"
#include "Common\xnacollision.h"

class BSModel : public Model
{
};
```

OrientedBoundingBox.h would be the same thing just with class OBBModel. So why am I getting the error
 `Error 2   error C2504: 'Model' : base class undefined c:\users\X\desktop\project\boundingsphere.h 9   1   PhysicsDemo`

I'm also getting 'Model' redefinition error.

Comment: Use consistent naming in your example. Don't use A,B,C if you have real names for them. And please show "Model.h".

Comment: do you have lines like the following in your base class?
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
#define HEADERFILE_H

Comment: Do you have `#ifndef` guards in your .h files? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) in the top of all the header files in your project to prevent re-including them once they have already been included.

`#pragma once` is supported on all modern compilers, but not standard. You can also use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which are standard.